# ASP.NET Core and .asmx

Tags: c#, web-services, asp.net-core

I have an ASP.NET Core application that uses the ASMX service. It works fine when I run it using IIS Express from Visual Studio or IIS (according to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/publishing/iis). If I use dotnet run (after dotnet publish), I get the error 404 when accessing the service. Can you tell me, please, what the reason of it is?

Answer (score 0):

Error 404 means File Directory not found.

```
1. Make sure all of your file after published are included.
2. To do that > on your Project Solution Explorer > select the folder where the file is content > Properties > Copy if Newer.
3. Clean > Rebuild > Publish.
```